# Automatically transpile TypeScript packages from other workspace in Turborepo

Tags: node.js, typescript, turborepo

I have a Turborepo-based monorepo in which I have one main TypeScript application (called `@myscope/tsapp`) which uses another TypeScript package in the same repository (called `@myscope/tspackage`). You can find the example repository I created for this question here: https://github.com/sigalor/typescript-transpile-workspace-packages

The file `apps/tsapp/src/index.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { sum } from "@myscope/tspackage";

console.log("The sum is:", sum(2, 3));
```

And the file `packages/tspackage/src/index.ts` simply contains this:

```js
export function sum(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}
```

Now running `npm run dev` in the root of the repository results in this:

```
> typescript-transpile-workspace-packages@0.0.0 dev
> turbo run dev

• Packages in scope: @myscope/tsapp, @myscope/tsconfig, @myscope/tspackage
• Running dev in 3 packages
• Remote caching disabled
@myscope/tsapp:dev: cache bypass, force executing 0f1217618b24762f
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 
@myscope/tsapp:dev: > @myscope/tsapp@0.0.0 dev
@myscope/tsapp:dev: > tsc-watch --onSuccess "node ./dist"
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 12:32:26 - Starting compilation in watch mode...
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 12:32:27 - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
@myscope/tsapp:dev: /home/cmd/typescript-transpile-workspace-packages/packages/tspackage/src/index.ts:1
@myscope/tsapp:dev: export function sum(a: number, b: number): number {
@myscope/tsapp:dev: ^^^^^^
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 
@myscope/tsapp:dev: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cmd/Downloads/typescript-transpile-workspace-packages/apps/tsapp/dist/index.js:3:19)
@myscope/tsapp:dev:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
@myscope/tsapp:dev: 
@myscope/tsapp:dev: Node.js v18.16.0
```

Of course it's clear for me why this happens: Obviously `@myscope/tspackage` is not transpiled by `tsc-watch`, so that it cannot be executed. But how can I fix this?

So far I made it so that I transpile `@myscope/tspackage` completely separately, see branch [`tspackage-transpiled`](https://github.com/sigalor/typescript-transpile-workspace-packages/tree/tspackage-transpiled) in the repository linked above. But then it's very tedious when I make changes to `@myscope/tspackage`, because I first have to quit tsc-watch from `@myscope/tsapp`, re-transpile `@myscope/tspackage` and then launch tsc-watch again.

I noticed that Next.js has the option `transpilePackages` which is exactly what I want, but of course only for the Next.js/frontend universe: https://github.com/vercel/turbo/blob/main/examples/basic/apps/web/next.config.js

Does an option like this exist for standard TypeScript as well, so that tsc (or tsc-watch) executed from within `@myscope/tsapp` also automatically transpiles `@myscope/tspackage`)?

Answer (score 1):

For now I'm using a script in my package which needs transpiling to call `tsc` during dev.

```json
// package.json
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc --watch"
  }
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveWatchOutput": true
  }
}
```

*Would be nice for this to be available in turborepo*